# Disable back button when changing Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a game that changes activities using intents during the gameplay. The problem is, you can press back after changing to a new activity with the Intent. Is there any way to disable that?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Better title.

Answer (score 1):

You can override your activity's [`onBackPressed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method to implement the back button behavior you need. A crude example would be:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    boolean suppressBackButton;

    public void openOtherActivityMethod() {
        suppressBackButton = true;
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!suppressBackButton) finish();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        suppressBackButton = false;
    }
}
```